# Pandas Groupby (shift) function to return null for first entry

Tags: python, pandas

For the following code, in python, I'm trying to get the difference between the latest rating, by date, minus the previous rating, which I have done in 'orinc'

However, where there's no previous rating - or the first entry for 'H_Name' it's returning the current rating. Is there anything to add to this code so this would return 'null' or 'nan'?

```
df2['orinc'] = df2['HIR_OfficialRating'] - df2.groupby('H_Name')['HIR_OfficialRating'].shift(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, check if values in column `H_Name` are unique, if yes, for each value after `shift` are returned missing values, because shifting for not exist previous value.

Also first value for each group is `NaN` for same reason.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'H_Name': ['a','a','a','a','e','b','b','c','d'],
    'HIR_OfficialRating': list(range(9))})

df2['new'] = df2.groupby('H_Name')['HIR_OfficialRating'].shift(1)
print (df2) 
  H_Name  HIR_OfficialRating  new
0      a                   0  NaN < first value of group a
1      a                   1  0.0
2      a                   2  1.0
3      a                   3  2.0
4      e                   4  NaN <-unique e
5      b                   5  NaN < first value of group b
6      b                   6  5.0
7      c                   7  NaN <-unique c
8      d                   8  NaN <-unique d
```

---

```
df2['orinc'] = df2['HIR_OfficialRating'] - df2.groupby('H_Name')['HIR_OfficialRating'].shift(1)
print (df2) 
  H_Name  HIR_OfficialRating  orinc
0      a                   0    NaN
1      a                   1    1.0
2      a                   2    1.0
3      a                   3    1.0
4      e                   4    NaN
5      b                   5    NaN
6      b                   6    1.0
7      c                   7    NaN
8      d                   8    NaN
```